# R: vectorize list without coercing NULL to 0

Tags: r, data-structures

I would like to know which elements of a list are 0. That is:

```
x <- list(1:3,4,0,NULL)
my_func(x)
[1] 3
```

The elements of the list can be both nested lists and NULLs. I thought of this solution:

```
x_vector <- sapply(x, length)
x_vector
[1]  3  1  0  0
```

As you can see, the problem is that function length() returns 0 for NULL. And even if it did not, I think sapply would end up coercing a NULL to 0, because all elements would have to be the same type.

I am trying to solve the question 2.b of the chapter [Functions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-components), from Wickham's *Advanced R*. The actual solution I am trying looks like this:

```
objs <- mget(ls("package:base"), inherits = TRUE)
funs <- Filter(is.function, objs)
funs_formals <- sapply(funs, function(x){length(formals(x))})
formals_vec[formals_vec==0]
# PROBLEM: NULLS are 0.
```

Comment: how about `sapply(x,is.null)` ?

Comment: When I repeat your code I get `x_vector` equal to `3 1 1 0`, not `3 1 0 0`.  The length of the `0` is `1`.  Only the `NULLs` will have length `0`.